# Proguard build failure with Lombok annotation library

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, lombok

Proguard is having issues with the Lombok library when using Gradle in Android Studio to complile the library. I found some config info to fix butterknife, the other annotation library we use.

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewInjector { *; }
-keepnames class * { @butterknife.InjectView *;}
```

Does anyone know the flags to add to make Lombok happy.

Proguard config file

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

# Optimizations: If you don't want to optimize, use the
# proguard-android.txt configuration file instead of this one, which
# turns off the optimization flags.  Adding optimization introduces
# certain risks, since for example not all optimizations performed by
# ProGuard works on all versions of Dalvik.  The following flags turn
# off various optimizations known to have issues, but the list may not
# be complete or up to date. (The "arithmetic" optimization can be
# used if you are only targeting Android 2.0 or later.)  Make sure you
# test thoroughly if you go this route.
#-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*,!code/allocation/variable
-dontobfuscate
#-optimizationpasses 5
-allowaccessmodification
-dontpreverify

# The remainder of this file is identical to the non-optimized version
# of the Proguard configuration file (except that the other file has
# flags to turn off optimization).

#-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
#-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewInjector { *; }
-keepnames class * { @butterknife.InjectView *;}
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

A few of the errors I'm seeing...

```
Warning:lombok.core.Agent$NetbeansPatcherInfo$1: can't find superclass or interface java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer
Warning:lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor: can't find superclass or interface javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor
Warning:lombok.delombok.DocCommentIntegrator$CommentAttacher_8$1: can't find superclass or interface com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Tokens$Comment
Warning:lombok.delombok.PrettyCommentsPrinter: can't find superclass or interface com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$Visitor
Warning:lombok.delombok.PrettyCommentsPrinter$1UsedVisitor: can't find superclass or interface com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner
Warning:lombok.delombok.ant.DelombokTask: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.tools.ant.Task
Warning:lombok.eclipse.EclipseAstProblemView$LombokProblem: can't find superclass or interface org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.DefaultProblem
Warning:lombok.eclipse.agent.ExtensionMethodCompletionProposal: can't find superclass or interface org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.InternalCompletionProposal
Warning:lombok.eclipse.handlers.SetGeneratedByVisitor: can't find superclass or interface org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ASTVisitor
Warning:lombok.installer.InstallerGUI$12: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.ActionListener
Warning:lombok.installer.InstallerGUI$13: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.ActionListener
Warning:lombok.installer.InstallerGUI$2: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.ActionListener
Warning:lombok.installer.InstallerGUI$3: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.ActionListener
Warning:lombok.installer.InstallerGUI$4: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.ActionListener
Warning:lombok.installer.InstallerGUI$6: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.ActionListener
Warning:lombok.installer.InstallerGUI$6$2: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter
Warning:lombok.installer.InstallerGUI$7: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.ActionListener
Warning:lombok.installer.InstallerGUI$8: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.ActionListener
Warning:lombok.installer.InstallerGUI$9: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.ActionListener
...
Warning: there were 10560 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 128 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
         You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
         be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)
Warning: there were 103 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
:just10:proguardGooglePhoneDevDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':just10:proguardGooglePhoneDevDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Comment: If your project is linking in java.awt or javax.swing classes, that's very suspicious -- those don't exist on Android.

Comment: @ScottBarta That's just Lombok's Eclipse installer that's embedded into the jar.

Comment: Lombok works with the source code and AFAIK Proguard works with JAR files only. Lombok has no runtime dependencies; you don't need it after compilation, so Proguard doesn't need and shouldn't see lombok.jar at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a `compile` directive in your gradle build file, change it to `provided`

In Eclipse, there's a similar solution where you can break the jar into a lombok-api.jar that you include in your libs. I tried looking for the instructions, but can't find the page that explained how you'd do that (This was over a year ago, so it may have changed).

Thanks to Roel (below), here's the commandline to use:
`java -jar lombok.jar publicApi`

Comment: You can use `java -jar lombok.jar publicApi` to generate this jar.

Comment: That's the one. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I added some flags to suppress warnings for the included libraries in my project and that did the trick.

```
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn lombok.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
-dontwarn com.sun.**
-dontwarn **retrofit**
```

Comment: Where did you put these statements?

Comment: Igor, I put in the proguard-config.txt file in the root directory of your android app.

Comment: But this would only be applicable for release builds.

Comment: Any build types that have "minifyEnabled" set to true would use it.